# Completeness of eigenvectors of Hermitian Matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra, eigenfunctions

How do you show that eigenvectors of a Hermitian matrix form a complete set of basis?

Answer (score 1):

In the same way how you do that for normal matrices.

1. Use or prove the Schur decomposition: for any square matrix $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$, there is a unitary $Q$ and triangular $T$ such that $A=QTQ^*$. A simple but very strong result which can be shown quite simply by induction.
2. Show that $A$ is Hermitian iff $T$ is Hermitian. A Hermitian triangular matrix is necessarily diagonal.
3. The eigenvectors can be then found stuffed in the columns of $Q$.